# Are Angular2 components downgraded by ng-upgrade compiled by Angular 1 at runtime

Tags: angularjs, performance, angular, angular2-aot, ng-upgrade

I have used ng-upgrade to bootstrap our Angular1 application as a hybrid app. I have AOT compiling the Angular2 scripts which contains 1 dummy component at the minute. I have also bundled the additional files and am running Angular2 in production mode.

The performance for our app is on average 2.5 seconds slower as a hybrid than a standalone Angular1 app. (Note this is a large app with a lot of components)

I expected a performance hit due to the extra files being downloaded and the extra scripting involved but the impact has come as a surprise

We plan to start migrating our components to Angular2 and downgrade them so they can be used with Angular1 but I'm wondering, will the downgraded components be compiled again after it has been compiled by the AOT?

If this is the case then we wont see a performance improvement until every component is migrated and we drop Angular1 which is a long way.

Has anyone gone down this route or can provide some information?